# jQRangeSlider fix start date and end date text position

Tags: javascript

I am using [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html). I am trying to fix the start date and end date text which right now moves as we move slider. 
Kindly suggest if anyone has any thoughts on this.

Comment: $("#rangeExample").rangeSlider({range: {min: 10, max: 20}}); use this http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#enabledOption

Comment: @cracker: thank you. But this is limiting the slider range. I just want to fix the date text position that appears above slider. I do not want dates to move with slider

Comment: Not sure why the above question is down voted. Whoever down voted care to explain?A lot of people with a high ratings seem to be have turned anarchist here. pheww

Comment: why you want to fix that label that shows the date when we slide it?

Comment: Because I want to show it in fixed positions below the slider. I do not have enough margins on the left and right of the slider. So, I just want to show the selected start and end date below the slider. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#formatterOption

At the website there is documentation about a formatter option which allows you to determine the text displayed. To fix the text, simply return a value not dependant on the value of the slider, as done here:

```
$("#slider").rangeSlider({
  formatter:function(val){
        return 'fixed text';
      }
});
```